# override styles for ant-design in create react app

Tags: create-react-app, antd

I am using ant-design in my CRA app, when I was trying to override the styles for ant component, I gave the element a className in react, but the styles from ant always overrode my styles, only by giving an ID worked.

The CRA app is not ejected but rewired with Less.

Here is how I want to use **but doesn't work**:

**In react component:**

```
<Card className="my-classname"><Card>
```

**In index.css:**

```
.my-classname { ... }
```

After googling a bit more, I found that className will not override the ant design but combine ant with my css style. So in the case where I tried to override the value that ant design had also specified, my css will not take effect unless I use ID specification.

My question now is should I only use ID so all my css overrides?

Comment: I think a better approach will create your own style sheet over css provided by antd and import that in your component. Stylesheet should contain same class name as of antd css class names. check example here https://codesandbox.io/s/pkxxr9n3xm

Answer (score 0):

The solution which I found after playing abit around the final html code which render in the browser is by overriding the styling of antd class. For ex:- I want to use my custom card styling in project. So, I override the ant-card-head for it. We can override any other class using this. You just have to inspect the rendered react in browser and find correct class associated with it.

```
.ant-card-head{
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```